# When I use Tor, I can't log in to Baidu

Tags: blocked-services

Although Tor can let me browse the site, but when I want to hide my IP, I found that I can't use Tor to login Baidu (a domestic website)...
I try to log in to other sites, QQ does log in, but not big.

I want to know, is there a way to use Tor browser without running Tor? I think I can login first, then open the Tor.

Comment: I don't think baidu is trying to block Tor users. I guess you need to "allow all this page" in NoScript setting. BTW: you can use qq account to login on baidu.

Answer (score 2):

This is a self beating procedure. As "nobody" has mentioned, "When you logged in without using Tor, you got your IP (address) correlated with your account, which can figure out your IP (address) even if you started Tor then". Now there is one additional issue, not only you are not anonymous but, the destination WEB site can figure out you are using Tor in addition to your ISP.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the proxy settings to use no proxy. When you logged in without using Tor, you got your IP correlated with your account, which can figure out your IP even if you started Tor then.